# D3: setting style conditionally with immediately invoked arrow function and ternary

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I'm going through the FreeCodeCamp beta curriculum for D3, and am trying to set color conditionally.

This attempt at setting it with an immediately invoked arrow function and ternary is not working.

```
.style("color", ((d)=>{
      d <20 ? return "red"; : return   "green";
    })());
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Among other problems, this is invlid syntax; `return` is a statement whereas the ternary operator expects expressions after the `?` and `:`. Anyway, why not just `d => d < 20 ? "red": "green"`? Whatever else

Comment: As above comment, can't have 2 return like that. If it's immediately invoked you also get `d = undefined` and then will always be green

Comment: Given the facts you presented, there is no need for an IIFE at all. Returning a string depending on the data you could keep it as simple as `.style("color", d => d < 20 ? "red" : "green")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @altocumulus said, the easiest way to do this is to pass d3's `style` setter a function:

```
.style("color", d => d < 20 ? "red" : "green")
```

D3 will solve this function given the value of `d` any time this line is called. If the data changes, and this `style` setter is called again, the color will update.

If that's *not* what you intended, you could use the anonymous closure as you do, with the following changes:

```
.style("color", (d =>
    d < 20 ? "red" : "green"
)(someVariable))
```

One reason you may want to do this is if the color depended on some dynamic variable which is not included in the data you passed to this selection, such as the current Date. You can pass this variable in by name in the place of `someVariable`.

The main issue with your current arrow function is that you do not pass it a variable inside the parentheses, so `d` will be undefined. The rest is just syntax:

1. In arrow functions, if the body of the function is a one-liner, the return statement is implied.
2. The ternary operator has it's own sort of "return"-ability. Think of it as a micro-function:

   ```
   var foo = (a ? b : c);
   ```

is essentially:

```
var foo = (function (a) {
    if (a) return b;
    else return c;
})(a);
```

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you.